# Writing to file in Flutter multiple times updates the file. Reading from the file always gives me the initial content

Tags: flutter, dart

SOLVED FOR MY SITUATION.  MORE INFORMATION HERE AND THEN ORIGINAL QUESTION BELOW.
===Solution===

Due to settings with Android external storage, the file_picker plugin creates a cache of the file you pick and stores it in a cache directory within the app storage location.  It will not overwrite this for files with the same name on subsequent reads. So for my read/write app, the solution was to do await file.delete(); when I was done with the read operation.  This ensures that the next read will then create a cached version with the updated contents

===Original Question===

I have some content in a database on a Flutter app I am using to just practice some new stuff in FLutter.  I have an export button that gets this data, JSON encodes it, and writes it to a file.
If I change the content and then export a second time, I can open the file on my device and see the updated content.  I also have an import button.  When I press that, I use FilePicker to select a file, read the contents of the file, and then JSON decode the data into an object.
I print out the file.readAsString and see the content from the initial write.
If I manually delete the file between writes then it works.  If I use file.delete() before the write, it does not work.  What can I do to get the updated text when I read from the file?

Getting file to write to. (I am aware this will only work on Android as is and that's fine)

```dart
Future<File?> _getBackupDataFile(String pathToTryFirst, ExportData data) async {
    Directory? directory = Directory(pathToTryFirst);
    if (!await directory.exists()) directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
    if ((await directory?.exists() ?? false) == false) {
      showErrorDialog(context: context, body: "Unable to find directory to save file.");
      return null;
    }

    return File("${directory?.path}/pm-account-backup.json");
}
```

Write to file as such (without the delete code):

```dart
Future<void> _writeDataToFile(ExportData data) async {
    try {
      File? file = await _getBackupDataFile('/storage/emulated/0/Download', data);
      if(file == null) { return; }
      await file.writeAsString(jsonEncode(data));
      await showSuccessDialog(context: context, title: "Success", body: "${data.accounts.length} accounts backed up successfully.");
    } catch (e) {
      showErrorDialog(context: context, body: "Failed to write data to file.");
    }
  }
```

Simplified file pick:

```dart
FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();
if (result != null) {
    String path = result.files.single.path ?? '';
    if((path).endsWith(".json")) {
          return File(path);
    }
}
```

Read from file as such:

```dart
String fileData = await file.readAsString();
print(fileData);
```

Comment: Needs more clarity! The database part seems working fine not sure what file you delete and what you are trying to write after delete. Can you elaborate on the delete part?

Comment: @user1613360 Sorry.  For when deleting works it's, manually opening the files app on my device, selected the file, and deleting it.  Deleting that didn't work is through code, calling file.delete().  It was just a test to see if programmatically deleting the file first would work.  I know that either way, I shouldn't have to delete a file to read from it and get updated data.

Comment: do not use `result.files.single.path` - for more read the second question here: https://github.com/miguelpruivo/flutter_file_picker/wiki/FAQ

Comment: @pskink thanks to the link I discovered more information and a solution.  With Android settings, the file_picker plugin has to cache the file from somewhere like public downloads.  It won't overwrite the cache on reads that follow.  I simply deleted the file in the created cache location after the import and from then one importing gets the latest version.  Thank you!

Comment: and why don't you simply use `readStream` or even `bytes` instead of `path`? with them you already have data, no extra steps needed to read  / delete any `File`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for my question found after more information provided by @pskink

Due to settings with Android external storage, the file_picker plugin creates a cache of the file you pick and stores it in a cache directory within the app storage location. It will not overwrite this for files with the same name on subsequent reads. So for my read/write app, the solution was to do await file.delete(); when I was done with the read operation. This ensures that the next read will then create a cached version with the updated contents